# Java Socket prevents panel?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, panel, frame

I am trying to create a panel while I have already connected to a server with socket, but in java it shows frame but not inside of frame. Panel is only shown after socket closed, but I need it while it is open. How can I solve this? It is because of a thread problem or I just missing something....
Thanks...

Comment: I believe it's because you are blocking on some socket operation and preventing the GUI from refreshing. Show some code ?

Comment: Its a big project and for an exception  in a func. I created a Jframe and try to display it. I also tried creating a new thread for this function but same situation.

Comment: use print statements to figure out whether the code to create a JFrame is actually called or not. Since it appears after the socket is closed, this is most probably a threading isuue.

Comment: Not "most probably", this is definitely a threading issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Long-running tasks should never occur on the EDT**. This includes blocking I/O operations. If such tasks do not modify any Swing components, simply use another thread. Otherwise, there are utilities available (e.g. [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [`SwingUtilties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html)) that will enable to you carry out long-running tasks in another thread, and then post the result as an action event on the EDT to modify any Swing components.

See also:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)